# Externalizable интерфейс

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Не могу разобраться с исключением.

Есть простой класс объекта, который нужно записать в файл:

```
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;

public class MessageToSerialize implements Externalizable {
    private int a = 13;

    public MessageToSerialize(){
    }

    public MessageToSerialize(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA(){
        return this.a;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.write(this.a);

    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.a = in.readInt();
    }
}
```

Есть класс, который пишет в файл сериализованный объект:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

//Class to persist the time in a flat file time.ser
public class PersistSerialClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "time.ser";

        if (args.length > 0) {
            filename = args[0];
        }

        MessageToSerialize data = new MessageToSerialize(2);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(data);
            System.out.println("Done!");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс, который получает из файла сериализованный объект:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

//Class to read the time from a flat file time.ser
public class ReadSerialClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "time.ser";

        if (args.length > 0) {
            filename = args[0];
        }

        MessageToSerialize data = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            data = (MessageToSerialize) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done: " + data.getA());
    }
}
```

В ответ на попытку десериализовать получаю ошибку:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at Testing.MessageToSerialize.readExternal(MessageToSerialize.java:30)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Testing.ReadSerialClass.main(ReadSerialClass.java:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Testing.ReadSerialClass.main(ReadSerialClass.java:32)
```

Вопрос: что я делаю не так? С обычным интерфейсом `Serializable` все работает нормально.

Comment: `EOFException` - наверное, Вы записываете меньше, чем считываете.

Comment: Вот есть у Эккеля пример, который у меня работет. Кажется, один в один

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Reconstructinganexternalizableobject.htm

Comment: Разгадка оказалась очень простой. в методе:

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.write(this.a);

    }

должно быть 

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeInt(this.a);

    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, решил проблему. Вот переработанный пример из Эккеля:

```
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Blip4 implements Externalizable {

    private byte[] array = {};

    public Blip4() {
    System.out.println("Blip4 Constructor");
    }

    public Blip4(byte[] array) {
    System.out.println("Blip4(byte[] array)");
    this.array = array;
    }

    public String toString() {
    return new String(this.array);
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Blip4.writeExternal");
    // You must do this:
    out.write(this.array);
    }

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Blip4.readExternal");
    // You must do this:
    in.read(this.array);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Constructing objects:");
    Blip4 b4 = new Blip4( new byte[]{ 100, 101, 102 } );
    System.out.println(b4);

    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Blip4.out"));
    System.out.println("Saving object:");

    o.writeObject(b4);
    o.close();
    // Now get it back:
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Blip4.out"));
    System.out.println("Recovering b4:");
    b4 = (Blip4) in.readObject();
    System.out.println(b4);
    }
}
```

Проблема оказалась в том, что private byte[] array; обьявить недостаточно, т.к. передается ссылка на массив, и ссылка равна null. При объявлении private byte[] array = {}; видимо выделяется память под массив, и уже есть на что указывать.